# Unable to create multiple log files based on the ThreadContext map values using routing appender in log4j2

Tags: java, oracle-adf, log4j2, threadcontext

I'm using the log4j2 jars in the oracle adf application build on 12c.

Requirement: Create multiple log files based on the session and ability to change the logging properties dynamically.

Log4j2.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" packages="apps.adfAppUI.ui.bean">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="file" fileName="./adfAppCustomLogs/TestLog4j2.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class %L %M - %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Routing name="AppRouting">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}">
                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has value 'user' for key ROUTINGKEY. -->
                <Route key="USER">
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-USER-${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}-${ctx:LOGGEDSESSIONID}" append="true" fileName="./adfAppCustomLogs/${ctx:ROUTINGKEY}-${ctx:LOGINID}-${ctx:LOGGEDSESSIONID}.log"
                                 filePattern="./adfAppCustomLogs/archive/${date:yyyy-MM}/${ctx:LOGINID}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.txt.gz">
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <Pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class %L %M - %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true" />
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="50 MB"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
        <Async name="async" bufferSize="1000" includeLocation="true">
        <AppenderRef ref="AppRouting" />
    </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="file" level="DEBUG"/> -->
            <AppenderRef ref="async"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I'm calling an utility class where the threadcontext values are set and clearled after logging.

Issue: Even though I change the threadcontext values for every session,I dont see multiple files being created. All the logs are appended to one file. But when I restart the server then a new file is generated and again all the session logs are being appended to it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below configuration will do the usecase.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <MapFilter onMatch="ACCEPT" operator="or">
        <KeyValuePair key="$${ctx:LOGLEVELYN}" value="Y"/>
    </MapFilter>
    <Appenders>
        <File name="file" fileName="./adfAppCustomLogs/TestLog4j2.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %class %L %M - %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Routing name="AppRouting">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:LOGGEDSESSIONID}">
                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has no value for key ROUTINGKEY. -->
                <Route key="$${ctx:LOGGEDSESSIONID}">
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-ALL" fileName="./adfAppCustomLogs/DefaultAll.log"
                                 filePattern="./adfAppCustomLogs/archive/${date:yyyy-MM}/DefaultAll-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.txt.gz">
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <Pattern>%X %d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %t %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                        </Policies>
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has value other than null for key ROUTINGKEY. -->
                <Route>
                    <RollingFile name="Rolling-OTHER-${ctx:LOGGEDSESSIONID}"
                                 fileName="./adfAppCustomLogs/${ctx:LOGINID}-${ctx:LOGGEDSESSIONID}.log"
                                 filePattern="./adfAppCustomLogs/archive/${date:yyyy-MM}/${ctx:LOGINID}-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.txt.gz">
                        <PatternLayout>
                            <Pattern>%X %d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %t %msg%xEx%n</Pattern>
                        </PatternLayout>
                        <Policies>
                            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="6" modulate="true"/>
                            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
                        </Policies>
                        <!-- <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="100"/> -->
                    </RollingFile>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
        <Async name="async" bufferSize="1000" includeLocation="true">
            <AppenderRef ref="AppRouting"/>
        </Async>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="file" level="DEBUG"/> -->
            <AppenderRef ref="async"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: In addition to the bare XML, could you also add the explanation what was the problem in your original XML?